# Touchpad vertical scrolling not working

Tags: touchpad, xinput, libinput

I am using ubuntu 18.04 and libinput for drivers. Scrolling is not working for my system. I have tried changing natural scrolling and two finger scroll option with all the combination, still it does not work. I ran this command

```
xinput --list-props 12
```

12 is the touchpad device id in my system
the output of above command

```
 Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
    Device Enabled (171):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (173): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Tapping Enabled (324): 1
    libinput Tapping Enabled Default (325): 0
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (326):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (327):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (328):   0
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (329):   0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (330):  1, 0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (331):  1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (306):   1
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (307):   0
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (332):    1
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (333):    1
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (308):    1, 1, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (309):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (310):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Click Methods Available (334): 1, 1
    libinput Click Method Enabled (335):    0, 1
    libinput Click Method Enabled Default (336):    1, 0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (313):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (314):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (315): 0.151079
    libinput Accel Speed Default (316): 0.000000
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (320): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (321): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (291): 1, 1
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (292):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (293):    0, 0
    Device Node (294):  "/dev/input/event6"
    Device Product ID (295):    2, 7
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (322):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (323):   1
```

My understanding is since in this list there is not libinput Vertical Scroll Option, I tried following command

```
sudo xinput set-prop 12 "310" 1,1,0
```

I tried above command all different combination but it gives same error everytime

```
X Error of failed request:  BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)
  Major opcode of failed request:  131 (XInputExtension)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  57 ()
  Serial number of failed request:  19
  Current serial number in output stream:  20
```

Please suggest some solution or any alternative if using any other package could solve it.

Comment: By looking at your `xinput list-props` output, I see values of scroll options are identical to mine *(which works)*. Something else going on. Try running `libinput debug-events --verbose` and then touch the touchpad. It should print available devices on the system, and then upon the touch it should print something like `event16 - button state: touch 0 from BUTTON_STATE_NONE    event BUTTON_EVENT_IN_AREA     to BUTTON_STATE_AREA`. Find the `eventXX` in the list of devices, is it the `SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad`? Side note: don't use IDs in `xinput`, they may change. Use a quoted string instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set the read-only property "libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default". You probably want to set the property "libinput Scroll Method Enabled" which is 309 (you can also just use the string instead of the number).